# Ruby - Why replacement is not iterate?

Tags: ruby, while-loop

I do not have more idea why in below code, replacement (indexRecord) doesn't work?

```
indexRecord = 0
bankFileRecord = 3
#add records
data = File.read("./Model/Bank/Record.xml")
while indexRecord < bankFileRecord do
    if indexRecord == 0
        replacedRecord = data.gsub(/(Valore=")(.*")/i, "\\1#{indexRecord+1}")
        f.puts replacedRecord
        indexRecord += 1
    else 
        replacedRecord = replacedRecord.gsub(/(Valore=")(.*")/i, "\\1#{indexRecord+1}")
        f.puts replacedRecord
        indexRecord += 1
    end
end
```

In all replaced elements I get Valore=0 (or other index declarate number). But when I printing indexRecord for debug, value is incrementing in print function.

I would like to have in each replaced line, value (Valore) incremented by 1.

Currentl in output i Have

```
<Date_records>
    <Date_general>
        <first TAG="A" Valore="1/>
        <second TAG="B" Valore="1/>
        <third TAG="C" Valore="1/>
    </Date_general>
</Date_records>
<Date_records>
    <Date_general>
        <first TAG="A" Valore="1/>
        <second TAG="B" Valore="1/>
        <third TAG="C" Valore="1/>
    </Date_general>
</Date_records>
<Date_records>
    <Date_general>
        <first TAG="A" Valore="1/>
        <second TAG="B" Valore="1/>
        <third TAG="C" Valore="1/>
    </Date_general>
</Date_records>
```

Input looks like this

```
<Date_records>
    <Date_general>
        <first TAG="A" Valore="X"/>
        <second TAG="B" Valore="X"/>
        <third TAG="C" Valore="X"/>
    </Date_general>
</Date_records>
```

Comment: It is not vary clear: what are you trying to achieve? What is expected result? What is current result?

Comment: thx for comment. Updated description.

Comment: Do you want to have it updated in the file or just in the memory. Could you also show what is the initial data? what is bankFileRecord? And why are you keep opening the same file in the loop?

Comment: I would like to have it updated in the output file. According to opened file, you are right, data read should be behind while loop. I will update shortly part of input file.

Comment: I suggest you to refactor your code to a more functional style, that is pretty bad code to debug (it is not very messy because it is short, but with ten more lines or more...)

Comment: Maybe it looks like that, because I already cut off many other functions to debug...

Comment: Another thing: XML editing using regex is considered a bad practice; you should use something more specific like [REXML](http://docs.rubydocs.org/ruby-2-1-2/classes/REXML.html) or Nokogiri f.e.

Comment: Yes, I know about that, and normally i do this, but in this case I just need to replace this one values to prepare file for validation. XML logic is out of scope for me in this case.

Comment: What is the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested the code you posted and it seems to work fine, so there must be something wrong with the parts you aren't showing us. If I had to guess I'd say that maybe `bankFileRecord` is 0 so the body of the while loop is never executed?

Edit:
I made a mistake when I ran your code myself, there was a small detail I didn't see. The problem is with your replacement string:

```
replacedRecord = data.gsub(/(Valore=")(.*")/i, "\\1#{indexRecord+1}")
```

should be changed to:

```
replacedRecord = data.gsub(/(Valore=")(.*")/i, "\\1#{indexRecord+1}\"")
```

you missed the closing speech mark. (you need to change it in both the gsubs)

Comment: Thank you for checking. I just make now CTRL+C and CTRL+V and still has the same result. Multiple records where all has Valore="1". :/

Comment: Also add bankingRecord = 3 (output will containt 3 data records). I also check if there came into if/esle and it properly flows by them.

Comment: @Artur_PL I've updated my answer with what I think is the problem

Comment: True(!) Great thanks! :) This solve issue. But this is interesting, why it do not crash or something without this signs? :|

Answer (score 0):

Missing '\"' make situation that in the ELSE Regular expresion does not much. Big thanks  @Doydle again and great sorry for messy issue :/